# is it possible to compile one android module using android.mk and replace it with the one in the phone?

Tags: android, build, android-ndk

I just want to know how  to build a single module in android from google repo.

I want to add/modify code a little bit in one library and then build a library and replace it with already installed library in the phone. (in my case the lib is fingerpirntd)

if not, then why google have android.mk file in git repo. (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-6.0.1_r79/fingerprintd/)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

For a normal, locked consumer phone - you can't replace the libraries. If you've rooted your phone, you should be able to remount the root partition into read-write mode and replace a library.

The fact that they have Android.mk files in the repo doesn't mean that you're supposed to build it using the NDK and update your phone with it. Originally, AOSP (Android Open Source Project) used Android.mk files as their build system; for the NDK they did a similar but simplified version with a subset of the same syntax as used for the full AOSP.

These days AOSP has migrated away from Android.mk files into a new Android.bp format instead, while the NDK still uses Android.mk files or CMake.

Comment: Thank your for reply. so lets assume that the device is rooted. so if I want to build one module. Do I need to download all the source code of AOSP from here (https://source.android.com/source/downloading) or I can use the mk file of this file ((https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-6.0.1_r79/fingerprintd/) to get the job done ?

Comment: The `Android.mk` file indicates that this library links to quite a few android platform libraries that aren't available in the NDK (libbinder, libhardware, libutils, libkeystore_binder), and the the source probably also requires quite a bit of headers from those libraries. It definitely is possible to hand pick the necessary parts from AOSP and do a bit of fiddling to build it using the NDK, but depending on the case, you might end up requiring quite a bit of the AOSP.

Comment: So your simplest option might still be simplest just to download it all, and then just build this library (set up the AOSP build environment but don't build it all, but just enter this directory and run `mm`).